# Checking color of an input to disable or enable a submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, input

I've set up a changing input background color dependent on validity of the input.

I am then checking the color with this code:

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("UserInput");
console.log(elem);

let theStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem, "").getPropertyValue("background-color");


if (theStyle === "rgb(234, 198, 198)") {
  document.getElementById("Submit").disabled = true;
}

if (theStyle === "rgb(251, 250 ,245)") {
  document.getElementById("Submit").disabled = false;
}
```

```css
input[type="number"]+div {
  display: none;
}

input[type="number"]:valid {
  background-color: #fbfaf5;
}

input[type="number"]:invalid {
  background-color: #eac6c6;
}

input[type="number"]:invalid+div {
  display: block;
  color: #c66464;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="UserInput" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" min="0" max="99999" step="0.01" value="" required />
<input type="submit" id="Submit" />
```

The only thing I am missing is how to continuously check the colour when active (it's already inside a called function). Currently the "disabled" is true because the rgb is that red. But when I get the color to change, ie I use a correct input, then I would like to enable the submit button. So, I guess I need an eventListener in there, but I just can't quite get the context.

Comment: Can you show the HTML structure? So we'll know how the event listener should look like in case this is the proper solution to your question?
Know that you can add a code snippet, that will make answering your question much easier:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers

Comment: Sure, I will add that in. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a code snippet that listens to the changes in the input field.
I am not sure exactly how the input value relates to the background value, so I'll leave that part to you to decide
But you can test it using the 2 buttons I added, changing the value when the background color is red make the submit button disabled
changing the value when the bg color is the right green leaves it enabled

In case there is not a suitable event that you can listen to in order to make this work, you can use setTimeout instead of event listener (every other solution I checked harms the site performance - slows it down significantly)

Also an important note:
you had a misplaced comma 'theStyle === "rgb(251, 250 ,245)"'
before the third parameter (Blue) value, the comma should come right after the second argument and then a space and then the third value.

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("UserInput");

elem.addEventListener('change', () => {
  let theStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem, "").getPropertyValue("background-color");
  let submitBtn = document.getElementById("Submit");

  if (theStyle === "rgb(234, 198, 198)") {
    submitBtn.disabled = true;
  } else if (theStyle === "rgb(251, 250, 245)") {
    submitBtn.disabled = false;
  }

});

document.querySelector("#valid-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "#fbfaf5";
});

document.querySelector("#invalid-btn").addEventListener('click', () => {
  elem.style.backgroundColor = "#eac6c6";
});
```

```css
input[type="number"]+div {
  display: none;
}



input[type="number"]:invalid+div {
  display: block;
  color: #c66464;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="UserInput" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" min="0" max="99999" step="0.01" value="" required />
<input type="submit" id="Submit" disabled/>

<button id="valid-btn">change bg to green</button>
<button id="invalid-btn">change bg to red</button>
```

Comment: I had a feeling this was going to work, but the disabling of the button isn't working. I am going to check my spelling etc.... could be that. But thank you, this has some potential.

Comment: It does work after clicking the 'change to red'. The reason is that you set the bg to be green explicitly by setting the bg with the :valid decorator
The input is actually valid from the beginning, so the bg is set to green on first change and the button keep being enabled

Comment: I removed any value, so the initial value is the red, and even then the button is not disabled. I think one of my problems with this one at the moment is I am too much of a noob to see where my error is, I am sure you've done it right, but I can't see where I haven't ;)

Comment: where do you use the bgstyle variable?

Comment: I mean, it is closer to working. But it takes some action in the "change" - it really needs to eventListen for everything. So I think I am missing something here.

Comment: Ok, I have found the issue... I can get it to work and it does work... but it's slow. I am using the wrong type of event. I tried with mousemove and it worked (but slowly) so I need to pick the correct event then i should be fine.

Comment: First - I edited the answer, the code snippet probably works now as expected

Comment: Second - The problem is with the CSS. You define the background color of the input to green if the *input* field is valid, which it is. therefore, even though it's initially red, it changes to green as soon as the user inserts any value
That's because you don't want to check the input field for valid/invalid attributes.
You want to check the submit button.
I removed some of the CSS, using the code of my original answer, I assume that is what you were aiming for

Comment: @PaulDavis was that answering your question? if so, please approve the answer

Comment: I've gone back with this answer and used keyup instead of change, it appears to work as anticipated. Thank you very much!

Comment: @PaulDavis Great news!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the onchange event handler(html), but this would happen every time you tried changing the value of the input, and I don't know how that would affect performance. Can't think of any better solution right now though. Example:

```
<input onchange="someFunc()">
```

Comment: If I can do this already inside the function that is working, it would be a great help. Also, I am not meant to be adding any onchange to the HTML, I have to do this by eventListeners (thanks, the idea is good).

Comment: selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) 

I just don't know how to write this into that syntax above... I know it is roughly what I need, I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: var element = document.getElementById("UserInput");
element.addEventListener("change", someFunc());
Try that, just throw it on the top of your code.

Comment: I tried, it doesn't seem to work. The console believes element is undefined.

Comment: Sorry: Uncaught TypeError: element is null

Comment: Oh, wait, I had a spelling error. I fixed that, but... it still isn't listening to all changes. Hmmmm.... I thought we had it.

Comment: Can you use jquery?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this question I before converted the colors to hexadecimal, this ensures that we'll not have to deal with spaces in rgb notation.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form')

const allowedColor = '#00ff00'
const forbiddenColor = '#ff0000'

const inputField = document.querySelector('#name')
inputField.style.backgroundColor = forbiddenColor // change this color to test

function componentToHex(c) {
  var hex = c.toString(16);
  return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(channels) {
  return "#" + componentToHex(Number(channels[0])) + componentToHex(Number(channels[1])) + componentToHex(Number(channels[2]));
}

function handleOnSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  
  const stringColor = window.getComputedStyle(inputField, null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
  
  const channelsColor = stringColor.substring(stringColor.indexOf('(') + 1, stringColor.indexOf(')')).split(',')
  
  const hexColor = rgbToHex(channelsColor)
  
  if (hexColor !== forbiddenColor) {
    console.log('submit')
    form.submit()
  }
}

form.addEventListener('submit', handleOnSubmit)
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <label for="name">Name: </label>
  <input id="name" type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I didn't need to convert - I used the console log, there's only two colors, and I have copied and pasted the console log outputs for both. I know I am getting the right two colours, because the console log. But, the issue I have isn't that, it's the fact that I can not get an eventListener to listen to the change of color :(

Comment: No worries about the conversion. But, anyway, I think you can use the logic above to test your submit event.

Answer (score 0):

I guess since you are already using valid property to change CSS styles I think you can use same to enable/disable submit button as well.

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("UserInput");
//listen to input and disable the submit based on the validity of input
elem.addEventListener('keyup',checkValidity);
elem.addEventListener('change',checkValidity);

function checkValidity(){
if(elem.validity.valid){
document.getElementById("Submit").disabled = false;
}else{
document.getElementById("Submit").disabled = true;
}
}

let theStyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem, "").getPropertyValue("background-color");
console.log(theStyle)

if (theStyle === "rgb(234, 198, 198)") {
  document.getElementById("Submit").disabled = true;
}

if (theStyle === "rgb(251, 250 ,245)") {
  document.getElementById("Submit").disabled = false;
}
```

```css
input[type="number"]+div {
  display: none;
}

input[type="number"]:valid {
  background-color: #fbfaf5;
}

input[type="number"]:invalid {
  background-color: #eac6c6;
}

input[type="number"]:invalid+div {
  display: block;
  color: #c66464;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="UserInput" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" min="0" max="99999" step="0.01" value="" required />
<input type="submit" id="Submit" />
```